# How would I read and write from multiple files in a single directory? Python

Tags: python, file, parsing, csv

I am writing a Python code and would like some more insight on how to approach this issue.

I am trying to read in multiple files in order that end with .log. With this, I hope to write specific values to a .csv file.

Within the text file, there are X/Y values that are extracted below:

Textfile.log:

```
    X/Y = 5
    X/Y = 6
```

Textfile.log.2:

```
    X/Y = 7
    X/Y = 8
```

DesiredOutput in the CSV file:

```
    5        
    6
    7
    8
```

Here is the code I've come up with so far:

```
    def readfile():
    import os
    i = 0
    for file in os.listdir("\mydir"):   
        if file.endswith(".log"):
            return file

    def main ():
            import re
        list = []
        list = readfile()

        for line in readfile():
            x = re.search(r'(?<=X/Y = )\d+', line)
            if x:
                list.append(x.group())
            else:
                break 
        f = csv.write(open(output, "wb"))
        while 1:
            if (i>len(list-1)):
                break
            else:
                f.writerow(list(i))
                i += 1

    if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I'm confused on how to make it read the .log file, then the .log.2 file.
Is it possible to just have it automatically read all the files in 1 directory without typing them in individually?

Update: I'm using Windows 7 and Python V2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to read files sequentially is to build a list and then loop over it.  Something like:

```
for fname in list_of_files:
    with open(fname, 'r') as f:
        #Do all the stuff you do to each file
```

This way whatever you do to read each file will be repeated and applied to every file in `list_of_files`.  Since lists are ordered, it will occur in the same order as the list is sorted to.

Borrowing from @The2ndSon's answer, you can pick up the files with `os.listdir(dir)`.  This will simply list all files and directories within `dir` in an arbitrary order.  From this you can pull out and order all of your files like this:

```
allFiles = os.listdir(some_dir)
logFiles = [fname for fname in allFiles if "log" in fname.split('.')]
logFiles.sort(key = lambda x: x.split('.')[-1])
logFiles[0], logFiles[-1] = logFiles[-1], logFiles[0]
```

The above code will work with files name like `"somename.log", "somename.log.2"` and so on.  You can then take `logFiles` and plug it in as `list_of_files`.  Note that the last line is only necessary if the first file is `"somename.log"` instead of `"somename.log.1"`.  If the first file has a number on the end, just exclude the last step

**Line By Line Explanation:**

- `allFiles = os.listdir(some_dir)`

This line takes all files and directories within `some_dir` and returns them as a list

- `logFiles = [fname for fname in allFiles if "log" in fname.split('.')]`

Perform a list comprehension to gather all of the files with `log` in the name as part of the extension.  `"something.log.somethingelse"` will be included, `"log_something.somethingelse"` will not.

- `logFiles.sort(key = lambda x: x.split('.')[-1])`

Sort the list of log files in place by the last extension.  `x.split('.')[-1]` splits the file name into a list of period delimited values and takes the last entry.  If the name is `"name.log.5"`, it will be sorted as `"5"`.  If the name is `"name.log"`, it will be sorted as `"log"`.

- `logFiles[0], logFiles[-1] = logFiles[-1], logFiles[0]`

Swap the first and last entries of the list of log files.  This is necessary because the sorting operation will put `"name.log"` as the last entry and `"nane.log.1"` as the first.

Comment: Ah I see, that makes a lot of sense. I'm a bit confused on the list_of_files parts though. How would the compiler know to read Textfile.log then Textfile.log.2 in order?

Comment: Is it possible to just have it automatically read all the files without typing them in individually?

Comment: @user3685687, yes, python is able to read files from a given directory.  Once you the list, you can [sort it fairly easily](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting) however you want

Comment: How exactly would i approach the "list_of_files" part? 
for fname in "\mydir"
 with open(fname, 'r') as f: ? Would this read all files in a directory?

Comment: @user3685687, depends on what OS you're using

Comment: I'm on Windows 7 using Python 2.7

Comment: Are you supposed to use the global module? files = glob.glob(path)   
for name in files:

Comment: @user3685687, there are several different ways, the easiest is probably with the ```os``` module as shown in The2ndSon's answer

Comment: Would you happen to have an alternate approach on his method if all the files end in .1 .2 or .3?

Comment: Very helpful. I'll implement this and let you know if I have any more issues. Have a great day :)

Comment: Quick question for now, is there any significance in lambda x? What does it mean?

Comment: See [this tuturial](http://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2011/08/29/lambda_tutorial/).

Comment: Thanks the tutorial helped a lot. My next question would be, "What is the significance of x.split('.')[-1])? Each time we encounter a '.', split the string, but what does the -1 mean? @wnnmaw

Comment: Is it a way to sort the files to start from Textfile.log.2 first instead of Textfile.log?

Answer (score 1):

If you change the naming scheme for your log files you can easily return of list of files that have the ".log" extension.  For example if you change the file names to Textfile1.log and Textfile2.log you can update readfile() to be:

```
import os
def readfile():
    my_list = []

    for file in os.listdir("."):
        if file.endswith(".log"):
            my_list.append(file)
```

print my_list will return ['Textfile1.log', 'Textfile2.log'].  Using the word 'list' as a variable is generally avoided, as it is also used to for an object in python.

Comment: Ah I see, unfortunately, it is part of the assignment. I was hoping that file.endswith could take in integers, but it doesn't :(

Comment: I'll incorporate your file reading method with wnnmaw's answer. Thanks a lot @The2ndSon